# ¿Cómo guardar una data frame desde R en formato excel?

Tags: r

Necesito imprimir una tabla que ya he formalizado como data frame con la orden `as.data.frame` en formato xlsx.
He instalado el paquete `xlsx` y la libreria `xlsx` y corro la orden:
`write.xlsx(lunes1, file = "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)`
y obtengo un error : `Error in write.xlsx(lunes1, file = "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE) :  no se pudo encontrar la función "write.xlsx"`

Comment: ¿ has importado la librería en el código en el comienzo del mismo ? prueba con: library(xlsx)

Answer (score 1):

En vista de que estas teniendo problemas con la función write.xlsx, te recomiendo lo siguiente:
Utiliza la función  `write.csv` , la misma es del paquete utils el cual por defecto ya viene instalado y cargado en Rstudio, por lo que no tendras que instalar ningún paquete.

`write.csv(lunes1, file = "lunes1.csv", row.names = FALSE)`

El archivo .csv que has conseguido puede ser abierto directamente en excel.
Una vez que lo hayas abierto en excel puedes guardarlo en formato xlsx si lo deseas, simplemente entrando a la ventana "archivos" y luego "guardar como".

Aunque, si no me equivoco, el archivo .csv puedes editarlo libremente en excel tal y como lo harías con un .xlsx, por lo tanto dependiento de tus fines capaz no sea ni necesario que lo guardes como .xlsx

Comment: Coincido: csv >> xlsx , es intrísencamente abierto, directamente legible por seres humanos y compatible con mucho más softaware.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta:

```r
xlsx::write.xlsx(lunes1, file = "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
```

O bien carga la librería primero:

```r
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(lunes1, file = "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Lo he hecho, es lo que digo en la descripción de la pregunta.                                          ``` install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)
 
lunes1=as.data.frame(L1)
write.xlsx(lunes1, file= "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
````  y obtengo  **Error in write.xlsx(lunes1, file = "lunes1.xlsx", row.names = FALSE) : 
  no se pudo encontrar la función "write.xlsx"**